# How to write custom inspection for duplicate annotations in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-inspections

Test methods is annotated with values, this values must be uniq.
I want an inspection in IDEA that highlights duplicate annotation. Duplicates may be in different java files

Example

```
@Link(type = "manual", value = "123456")<-this must be highlighte
void someTest1(){
}

@Link(type = "manual", value = "654321")
void someTest2{
}

@Link(type = "manual", value = "123456")<-and this must be highlighted, because of the same value
void someTest3(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a feature request for the inpsection at YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA
or you may also implement such an inspection as plugin using the available sources:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community